# How to track how many users logged in using Google One Tap Sign Up

Tags: google-signin, google-identity, google-smartlockpasswords

I want to track how many users login/Sign up using one tap Sign up feature

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, we don't provide any externally available metrics for this, you'd have to keep track of it using your own analytics systems. e.g. in Google Analytics, track when user signs in or up based on the results from your backend

Comment: Can we track the account suggestion widget that opens if user is logged in on browser with a gmail account

Comment: and can we request user phone number in one tap sign up ?